# How to get min date of every month for six months?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have data like this.

```
Process_date   SEQ_No
-------------  ---------
16-MAR-13   733
09-MAR-13   732
02-MAR-13   731
24-FEB-13   730
16-FEB-13   728
09-FEB-13   727
02-FEB-13   726
26-JAN-13   725
21-JAN-13   724
12-JAN-13   723
05-JAN-13   722
29-DEC-12   721
24-DEC-12   720
15-DEC-12   719
08-DEC-12   718
03-DEC-12   717
22-NOV-12   716
17-NOV-12   715
10-NOV-12   714
03-NOV-12   713
29-OCT-12   712
23-OCT-12   711
13-OCT-12   710
05-OCT-12   709
28-SEP-12   708
22-SEP-12   707
15-SEP-12   706
08-SEP-12   705
01-SEP-12   704
```

Every month admin will refresh actual data table and automatically this above table will update with unique seq_no and process_date.

I need to extarct min date of everymonth(First refresh of last 6 months - excluding currrent month) and also seq_no related to that month so using joins(using seq_no - that is available in main table) i can combine actual data.

I need result like:

```
02-MAR-13   731 ( I don't need MAR as it should not take current month data)
```

so i  need final result like below:

```
02-FEB-13   726
05-JAN-13   722
08-DEC-12   718
03-NOV-12   713
05-OCT-12   709
01-SEP-12   704
```

--sorry for asking direct quetion like this. I am not sure how to do that. thats the reason i have not prepared/posted any query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Process_date, SEQ_No
  from (select Process_date, SEQ_No, 
               row_number() over (partition by trunc(process_date, 'mm') order by process_date) rn
          from yourtab
         where Process_date < trunc(sysdate, 'mm'))
 where rn = 1;
```

will do that

fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5452/1

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understood how seq_no is in another table...
But using the input data:

```
select 
    min(process_date), 
    min(seq_no) keep (dense_rank first order by process_date)
from 
    your_table
where 
    process_date between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),-7) 
                     and last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1))
group by 
    trunc(process_date,'MM');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT seq_no,process_date FROM my_table
WHERE process_date IN (SELECT min(process_date) 
                       FROM my_table 
                       GROUP BY TRUNC(process_date,'MM'))
```

Comment: You should flash out your answer a bit.